# How can I control a specific command to be not executed in my terminal?

Tags: linux, bash, terminal, sudo

I need to control some commands to be not executed in my terminal for example I want to control `$ sudo rm -rf /*` to avoid big troubles in my linux machine.

Answer (score 1):

That's not how Linux or process control works.

If you use sudo, you will be able to delete all files. `rm -rf /` is not the only way to do that; `find / -delete` is another one, `rm -f /**/**` yet another one, and you could write infinitely more programs that do the same.

So, *when using sudo, you become the super user, with super powers, and super responsibilities*. So, **never** use `sudo` without thinking. That's the best that's possible on your linux system, sorry!

Forbidding a specific "text" to be executed at your command line doesn't help, as there's infinitely many ways to damage your system. Using the Unix-style system of privileges (and lack thereof) is what you can do. That's literally why you need *sudo* in the first place.

Comment: Yes, I know there are a lot of ways not just `rm -rf /` I just make that as an example that's why I am asking how can I control them even using `sudo`.

Comment: you can't sensibly. Again, blocking individual commands makes no sense. There's infinitely many ways to screw up your system, and you can only block finitely many words. So, what you want is simply the wrong way. This consideration is literally > 50 years old! Back then, people realized that "blocking the wording of harmful commands" never works, you need to block the effects. And that's what the permission system in Linux already does, unless you *circumvent it*, explicitly, using sudo. So, what you want to do is not taking you anywhere.